# Irvine32 SmallWin.inc causing errors

Tags: assembly, io, masm, irvine32

I'm getting 20 errors from the SmallWin.inc in the Irvine32 library. All of the errors are "non-benign structure redefinition" but with "incorrect initializers" + "too few labels" + "too few initializers" + "too few labels". All of the errors stem from the lines roughly 200-300. My program is a recursive multimodule GCD in masm using INVOKE and PROTO

prog4.asm

```
include Irvine32.inc
include gcd.asm

.data
ask byte "enter y integers: "
answer byte "the gcd of the y numbers: "
x sdword ?
y sdword ?

.code
main PROC
    call Clrscr

    mov edx, OFFSET ask ; get variables
    call WriteString
    call ReadDec
    mov x, eax
    call ReadDec
    mov y, eax
    ; have variables
    invoke GCD, x, y ; returns to eax
    mov edx, OFFSET answer
    call WriteString
    call WriteInt
main ENDP
END
```

gcd.asm

```
include Irvine32.inc

GCD PROTO,x:dword,y:dword

.code

;-----------------------------
GCD PROC, x:dword, y:dword
; calculate the gcd of two unsigned ints in recursion
; receives x,y
; returns eax = gcd
;-----------------------------
    mov eax,x
    mov ebx,y
    mov edx,0 ; clear high dividend
    div ebx     ; divide x by y
    cmp edx,0 ; remainder = 0?
    je L2           ; yes:quit

    INVOKE GCD,ebx,edx ; recursive call

    L2:
        mov eax,ebx ; eax = gcd
        ret
GCD ENDP
END
```

Comment: You `include gcd.asm` which again has `include Irvine32.inc`. If you want a single file, remove the `include Irvine32.inc` from `gcd.asm` (possibly also the `END`). If you want to assemble two files and link them, then remove the `include gcd.asm`.

Comment: i need it in two files so i removed the ```include gcd.asm``` but now I am getting undefined symbol:gcd. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio if that helps

Comment: You should move the `GCD PROTO,x:dword,y:dword` into `prog4.asm` and you might need to add `PUBLIC GCD` to `gcd.asm`.

Answer (score 0):

final code that compiled and ran
prog4.asm

```
include Irvine32.inc

gcd PROTO,x:dword,y:dword

.data
ask1 byte "enter the first integer: ", 0
ask2 byte "enter the second integer: ", 0
answer byte "gcd: ", 0
x dword ?
y dword ?

.code
main PROC
    call Clrscr
    mov edx, OFFSET ask1
    call getX  ; get variables
    mov edx, OFFSET ask2
    call getY
    ; have variables
    invoke gcd, x, y ; returns to eax
    mov edx, OFFSET answer
    call PrintResult
    exit
main ENDP

GetX PROC
    call WriteString    ; print message
    call ReadDec            ; get x
    mov x,eax
    ret
GetX ENDP

GetY PROC
    call WriteString    ; print
    call ReadDec            ; get y
    mov y,eax
    ret
GetY ENDP

PrintResult PROC
    call WriteString
    call WriteDec
    ret
PrintResult endp
END main
```

gcd.asm

```
include Irvine32.inc

.code

gcd PROC, x:dword, y:dword
    ; calculate the gcd of the two unsigned ints in recursion
    ; receives x,y
    ; returns gcd in eax
    mov eax,x
    mov ebx,y
    mov edx,0                ; clear edx aka high dividend
    ;
    cmp ebx,0                ; stop condition
    je L1
    div ebx                      ; a / b // remainder in edx
    invoke gcd,ebx,edx ; recursive call gcd(b, a mod b)

    L1:
        ret
gcd endp
END
```